# I'm struggling with coinbase, i want to make an app using django that accept users to buy coins with cyptocurrency

Tags: django, cryptocurrency, coinbase-api

i was working in a project and the client ask me to add a way to let users buy coins (coins are the balance of the users so they can buy tickets)
what i want is if someone can help me to know how to do it by using coinbase because it is not possible in my country to use another way

Answer (score 0):

you can use coinbase lib in python and integrate it to client requirement. ||
visit to coinbase api docs and make own requests to the api using api key or secret key